Docker doesn't build the "welcome-to-docker" image, it stays in the last step
I just installed Docker from the official website.
I'm following the Docker Desktop tutorial. At the time of building my image, it stays indefinitely in step:
[6/6] RUN npm install && npm install -g serve && npm run build && rm -fr node_modules

Docker version: 6.0.0, build 2ae903e
S.O: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core
I've already tried canceling the operation and doing it again with docker build -t welcome-to-docker.
And I've also already tried deleting the package_lock.json

Please provide your Dockerfile.

Divide steps
https://www.docker.com/blog/getting-started-with-docker-using-node-jspart-i/
Use this one
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --verbose

COPY src/ .

COPY public/ .

RUN npm run build

And provide package.json

I was having kind of similar issue in my next step where RUN ["npm", "start"] was taking too long So i used CMD ["npm", "start"] somehow it worked.

"somehow it worked" is not helpful, not even clear how your topic could help fixing the issue.
